# how can i connect pythonanywhere to mongodb knowing that i'm using django to backend?

Tags: django, mongodb, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to deploy my django app to pythonanywhere.com the problem is that i couldn't connect my app on that server to my mongodb database i already changed the mongo_client host to mongo url by going on pythonanywhere to

/home/myusername/.virtualenvs/Myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py

i changed the host to :
HOST = "mongodb+srv://<*myUsername*>:<*password*>@<*myCluserName*>.rkait.mongodb.net/<*MyDBname*>?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
(of course i changed the <> fields)

But i'm getting this error

```
    [Errno 111] Connection refused,myClusterName-shard-00-02.rkait.mongodb.net:27017: 
    [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

so is there any solution to make that connection with mongodb ?
and if that is not possible please recommend me another hosting website that support django and mongodb for free.

Comment: Are you using a free account?  PythonAnywhere restricts Internet access for free accounts -- they can only use HTTP or HTTPS, and can only access sites that are on a [whitelist](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/).  MongoDB uses its own protocol, not HTTP or HTTPS, so it won't work.

Comment: @GilesThomas oh i see , otherwise is there any other server that support django and mongodb for free ?

Comment: another reason could be that you did not authorize the machine's ip. But most likely Giles's comment is more correct.